# ASP C# RequiredFieldValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

```
[textbox1]

[textbox2]

[button1] [linkbutton1]
```

i have 2 `textboxes`, 2 `RequiredFieldValidator`, `button1` and `linkbutton`.
the button1 and 2textboxes are working properly with RequiredFieldValidator, but if i click the linkbutton the RequiredFieldValidator also appears.

I want the `RequiredFieldValidator` focus only in `button1`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `CausesValidation="false"` in your link button markup like this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify Validation Groups

```
 <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator2"
      controltovalidate="AgeTextBox"
      validationgroup="PersonalInfoGroup"
      errormessage="Enter your age."
      runat="Server">
    </asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use `ValidationGroup` property of `RequiredFieldValidator`.

Set the `ValidataionGroup="someName"` for your `textbox1-requiredfieldvalidator`, `textbox2- requiredfieldvalidator` and your `button1` control.

Note: Keep the name of the `ValidationGroup` same.